# How can I change the line-height in Terminal OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to adjust the line-height, vertical spacing in between lines, in the OS X Terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Terminal** > **Preferences...**, **Settings** tab.

Select the theme you are using and click the **Change...** button on the **Text** tab. **Line Spacing** is at the bottom.

[image: Terminal Settings]

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Thanks!

Comment: This also works for iTerm2, in case you are in the similar situation as me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Menlo font (OS X default), you can try [Meslo](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font/), a modified version of Menlo that comes in various line-heights. This allows you to adjust the line-spacing in apps that don't have line-spacing adjustment like Terminal (i.e. MacVim).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can adjust line height and spacing in **iTerm**.

`iTerm > Preferences > Profiles tab > Text`

Once you are looking at the Text pane inside of the Profiles tab, click the `Change Font` button under Regular Font.

The Fonts dialog will include a slider for horizontal and vertical character spacing. Adjusting the vertical value will affect the line height inside of the terminal inside of iTerm.

[image]