# Increase the space between lines in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I think the title says it all. I've done my homework and the only command that I found was:

```
:set linespace=3
```

but it doesn't seem to work, neither on the Mac nor in Linux.

Edit: In Mac OSX you can actually configure the terminal to add to (max 1.5) lines
[How can I change the line-height in Terminal OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/350821/how-can-i-change-the-line-height-in-terminal-osx)
If anyone know how to increase more than 1.5, that'd be helpful

Thanks

Comment: if you've done your homework, you should see `{only in the GUI}` in help doc. and your question tagged with `terminal`

Comment: Related question: [Adding vertical space between lines in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1287545).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`linespace`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27linespace%27) is only available for the GUI version, i.e. gVim or MacVim, and not console Vim. So maybe you are trying in your terminal?

```
'linespace' 'lsp'       number  (default 0, 1 for Win32 GUI)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
                        {only in the GUI}
```

If you want to modify the linespacing of your terminal you have to do it in your terminal settings, not in Vim. (Maybe you can do it programmatically in your `.vimrc`.)

Answer (score 2):

you can' use linespace in terminal mode , it is for GUI only

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the space between lines for terminal (xterm) by adding the line `xterm*scaleHeight: 1.1` to my *.Xresources* file and executing `xrdb ~/.Xresources` command after saving the file. As a result after relaunching the terminal, text in vim editor has increased space between lines.